# errorMessage": "'Neptune' object has no attribute 'stop_db_cluster"

Tags: python, aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-neptune

The following code is given below for my lambda funciton

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('neptune') response =
client.stop_db_cluster(DBClusterIdentifier='qa-n1-cluster')
```

output is given below

> Response: {   "errorMessage": "'Neptune' object has no attribute
>   'stop_db_cluster'",   "errorType": "AttributeError",   "stackTrace": [
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 702, in _load\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 783, in exec_module\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
>       "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 4, in \n    response =
>   client.stop_db_cluster(DBClusterIdentifier='qa-n1-cluster')\n",
>       "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 514, in **getattr**\n    raise AttributeError(\n"   ] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop_db_cluster() and start_db_cluster() are newer APIs (only released as of a couple of weeks ago.  Can you please validate that you're on the latest version of boto3?

pip install --upgrade boto3

Comment: yes, i referred this link.. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Comment: looks like, it is working on terminal with out any development tool.. we are facing the same issue in pycharm since updated the boto3 version.. my current boto3 version is 1.12.19 in pycharm

Comment: C:\Users\keswarm\venv\AWS-jobs-automate\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/keswarm/PycharmProjects/AWS-jobs-automate/neptune.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/keswarm/PycharmProjects/AWS-jobs-automate/neptune.py", line 5, in <module>
    sn = client.stop_db_clusters(DBClusterIdentifier=clustername)
  File "C:\Users\keswarm\venv\AWS-jobs-automate\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 566, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'Neptune' object has no attribute 'stop_db_clusters'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: AWS-jobs-automate) C:\Users\keswarm\PycharmProjects\AWS-jobs-automate>pip show boto3
Name: boto3
Version: 1.12.19
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: c:\users\keswarm\venv\aws-jobs-automate\lib\site-packages
Requires: jmespath, s3transfer, botocore

Answer (score 2):

You need boto version 1.11.721 (2020-02-12) or higher to be exact.

Change Log: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

> 1.11.721 2020-02-12
>
> Amazon Neptune
>
> This launch enables Neptune start-db-cluster and stop-db-cluster. Stopping and starting Amazon Neptune clusters helps you manage costs for development and test environments. You can temporarily stop all the DB instances in your cluster, instead of setting up and tearing down all the DB instances each time that you use the cluster.

Upgrade your boto version, and confirm that you are on a version newer than this.