# errorMessage“: ”'Neptune' object has no attribute 'stop_db_cluster"

Tags: boto3, amazon-neptune

Even which is not running on boto3 version 1.12.19 updated version

depend on this ticket, [errorMessage": "'Neptune' object has no attribute 'stop_db_cluster"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528110/errormessage-neptune-object-has-no-attribute-stop-db-cluster)

Comment: I made an edit to change the tag from neptune to amazon-neptune. That way more people will likely spot your post.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested Amazon Neptune API with boto3 version 1.12.19 successfully as follows :

My sample code:

```py
import json
import boto3

def main():

    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='syumaK')
    # Any clients created from this session will use credentials
    # from the [syumaK] section of ~/.aws/credentials.

    NeptuneClient = session.client('neptune')

    # print(boto3.__version__)

    response = NeptuneClient.start_db_cluster(
        DBClusterIdentifier='syumak-test-cluster'
    )

    print response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My sample response:

[image]

Resolution Steps:

***1. Check the current version of boto3 :***

```
pip show boto3
```

or

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
```

If the output is anything less than the current version (1.12.19
) then proceed to upgrade your boto3 version as shown below.

***2. Upgrade your boto3:***

```
pip install botocore --upgrade
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

Note: You'll need to log out for the changes to take effect

Hope this helps!